# sleep at the main thread by using pthread C/C++

Tags: c, pthreads

Hello I am new to pthread and, trying to test this program.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-posix3/

This program is working very well, but one thing. what is this sleep() in main thread?
if I change it to sleep(2) to shorter or putting more task on this *threadfunc.

The thread finish before completing the all tasks.
Is there any better way to wait until the task finish?

Comment: I found the solution,,,this is it. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154539/how-can-i-wait-for-any-all-pthreads-to-complete)

Comment: Then what you've done to this specific program?

Comment: Yes I changed the program in that way, and it is waiting until the task complete!

Answer (score 0):

The `sleep()` suspend the main thread, so the worker threads do the work for a time. After the main thread wakes up, it deactivates the work queue, so `wq.control.active` in `threadfunc()` is false, the worker threads terminate no matter whether the threads finish their tasks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any better way to wait until the task finish?

Just join it using `pthread_join()`, the call would block until the thread to be joined ended.